# Counter animation for Django variable

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I want to do one of those cool dashboard counter animations using my Django variables. My code isn't rendering any numbers yet so I'm doing something wrong.

Something like this if what I'm after:

[image]

Here's my code so far:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="card m-2 p-4">
                <i class="counter-icon fa fa-users"></i>
                <h2 class="users-count"></h2>
                <h3 class="count-label">Users</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="card m-2 p-4">
                <i class="counter-icon fa fa-handshake-o"></i>
                <h2 class="dealers-count"></h2>
                <h3 class="count-label">Dealers</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="card m-2 p-4">
                <i class="counter-icon fa fa-address-card"></i>
                <h2 class="staff-count"></h2>
                <h3 class="count-label">Employees</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="card m-2 p-4">
                <i class="counter-icon fa fa-eye"></i>
                    <h2 class="visitors-count"></h2>
                <h3 class="count-label">Visitors Today</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>    
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
 function counter(id, start, end, duration) {
  let obj = document.getElementsByClassName(id),
   current = start,
   range = end - start,
   visitors_range = 11 - start,
   increment = end > start ? 1 : -1,
   step = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range)),
   timer = setInterval(() => {
    current += increment;
    obj.textContent = current;
    if (current == end) {
     clearInterval(timer);
    }
   }, step);
 }
 counter("users-count", 0, {{users.count}}, 3000);
 counter("dealers-count", 100, {{dealers.count}}, 2500);
 counter("staff-count", 0, {{staff.count}}, 3000);
 counter("visitors-count", 0, {{visitors.count}}, 3000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: You don't share the Python code, are you sure that `users.count` etc are doing what you expect? A quick way to check that is to view the source and see how those function calls are rendered.

Comment: Also, while this shouldn't cause the animations to not run at all, you will need to put `let` before the `timer = setInterval(...)`. As it is now you've only got one, global, `timer` variable, and I expect the result, once the other problem is sorted, to be that all animations other than the last fail to stop when they should.